# how can I get cursor data with calling stored procedure in npgsql

Tags: c#, npgsql

I have looked into materials in [www.npgsql.org](http://www.npgsql.org), but couldn't find how to solve my problem...

**Table, PostgreSQL**

```
[City], [State]
"Austin", "TX"
"Houston", "TX"
"Los Angeles", "CA"
"San Diego", "CA"
"San Fransisco";"CA"
"St.Louis", "MO"
```

**Function (stored procedure), PostgreSQL**

```
-- Procedure that returns a single result set (cursor) 
   CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION show_cities() RETURNS refcursor AS $$
    DECLARE
      ref refcursor;
    BEGIN
      OPEN ref FOR SELECT city, state FROM cities;
      RETURN ref;                                 
    END;
    $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

**Code, C#**

```
using (NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbConnection"].ConnectionString))
{
    conn.Open();
    using (NpgsqlTransaction tran = conn.BeginTransaction())
    {
        using (var command = new NpgsqlCommand("show_cities", conn))
        {
            command.Transaction = tran;
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            NpgsqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader();

            while (dr.Read())
                str += dr.GetValue(0);

            dr.Close();
        }
        tran.Commit();
    }
}
```

This returns "unnamed portal 1" and it's a cursor to be fetched not data,
Is there any way to convert this to data like *Austin, Houston, Los Angeles...* ?

There are some posts over internet about this, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

- npgsql : ver3.0.3
- c# : vs2012

(added)
I have found this is happening at npgsql ver3.x, while in ver2.x it is working fine with my code. Is there any change in usage for fetching cursor ?

(reference)
http://www.sqlines.com/postgresql/npgsql_cs_result_sets

Comment: can you tell us why you are using a function with a cursor and not a simple view or select statement!???

Comment: the "city,state" example and how to work with resultsets: http://www.sqlines.com/postgresql/npgsql_cs_result_sets

Comment: @CeOnSql yes, you are right. I'm going to make many functions in my web site, so I would like to create each as a function to return result set. If I have a lot of command text "select * from cities where city = $1" in my program, it would be not easy to maintain further I guess... thanks !

Comment: @CeOnSql oh yes.. that site is what I was looking into :D but even I try it as described, it only returns "unnamed portal xx" cursor, not data. am I doing something wrong..?

Comment: Sorry i am no PostgreSQL expert at all - more SQL Server ;) But @Shay provided a perfect anwer!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Npgsql 2.x had a feature whereby it automatically "dereferenced" cursors returned from functions. This feature was dropped from Npgsql 3.0; this is mentioned in our migration nodes for 3.0, and the discussion is in [this issue](https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/438). Since the cursor is simply returned and isn't dereferenced, Npgsql returns the cursor name itself (unnamed portal 1); you can now fetch results from this query by sending `FETCH` etc.

However, as was mentioned, wrapping a single SELECT in a function doesn't make much sense. If you do need to write a function that returns a *single* resultset, make it return a SETOF or a TABLE instead of a cursor: `CREATE FUNCTION ... RETURNS TABLE (column_name column_type [, ...])`. Apart from being simpler and cleaner, this is also more efficient, as the query results are returned directly (dereferencing the cursor involves another database roundtrip).

See the [PostgreSQL docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createfunction.html) for more info on how to define a function returning a table.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! with your help last night I found it is related to changes in "dereferenced cursors feature", let me look into it and will update my code.

Comment: And in my code "show_cities" is for easy Q&A example, actually I have more than 20 data columns for each row, so I thought it would be good to create this as a function. Let me create it to return __SETOF__ or __TABLE__ for better solution, thanks again :D

Comment: Glad it helped. I'm still not convinced about wrapping a single SELECT, no matter how many columns it returns, in a plpgsql function... As @CeOnSql mentioned above, a view seems much better adapted to this. And even if you really want to use a function, an SQL rather than a plpgsql function is probably simpler.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but the RETURNS TABLE would be a great solution if our SQL statements were returning static table structures. For functions returning variable column lists, would the FETCH xxxx be the only way to handle it?

Answer (score 19):

With Shay's help, I figured out how we can fetch cursor in v3.x after removal of "[dereferenced](https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/438)" feature.
I think there are not much of good example on this, I hope this might help people save time to search example.

You can do this in npgsql ver3.x

**1. CommandType.StoredProcedure** (cursor name not defined)

```
conn.Open();
NpgsqlTransaction tran = conn.BeginTransaction();

NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand("show_cities", conn);
command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
command.ExecuteNonQuery();

command.CommandText = "fetch all in \"<unnamed portal 1>\"";
command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

NpgsqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader();
while (dr.Read())
{
    // do what you want with data, convert this to json or...
    Console.WriteLine(dr[0]);
}
dr.Close();

tran.Commit();
conn.Close();
```

**2. CommandType.StoredProcedure** (cursor name defined)

```
conn.Open();
NpgsqlTransaction tran = conn.BeginTransaction();

NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand("select show_cities(@ref)", conn);
command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
NpgsqlParameter p = new NpgsqlParameter();
p.ParameterName = "@ref";
p.NpgsqlDbType = NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Refcursor;
p.Direction = ParameterDirection.InputOutput;
p.Value = "ref";
command.Parameters.Add(p);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();

command.CommandText = "fetch all in \"ref\"";
command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

NpgsqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader();
while (dr.Read())
{
    // do what you want with data, convert this to json or...
    Console.WriteLine(dr[0]);
}
dr.Close();

tran.Commit();
conn.Close();
```

**3. CommandType.Text** (cursor name defined)

```
conn.Open();
NpgsqlTransaction tran = conn.BeginTransaction();

NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand("select show_cities(@ref)", conn);
command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
NpgsqlParameter p = new NpgsqlParameter();
p.ParameterName = "@ref";
p.NpgsqlDbType = NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Refcursor;
p.Direction = ParameterDirection.InputOutput;
p.Value = "ref";
command.Parameters.Add(p);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();

command.CommandText = "fetch all in \"ref\"";
command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

NpgsqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader();
while (dr.Read())
{
    // do what you want with data, convert this to json or...
    Console.WriteLine(dr[0]);
}
dr.Close();

tran.Commit();
conn.Close();
```

(reference for v2.x) http://www.sqlines.com/postgresql/npgsql_cs_result_sets

This is example for easy understanding, so if you want your function to return single result set, then instead of returning `cursor`, please consider it to return `table` as @Shay suggested or create a `view` not a `function` as @CeOnSql suggested.

Thanks !

Comment: This is the only code that worked for me after 2 days of trying different examples. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

I have following working code with [Npgsql 2.2.7](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Npgsql/2.2.7) version:

```
 private static DataSet ExecuteFunction(string functionName)
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        var conn = new NpgsqlConnection("replace with connection string");
        conn.Open();
        var tran = conn.BeginTransaction();
        var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(functionName, conn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        NpgsqlDataAdapter da = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(ds);

        //foreach (DataRow r in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
        //{
        //    Console.WriteLine("{0}", r[0]);
        //}

        tran.Commit();
        conn.Close();
        return ds;
    }
```