# PostgreSQL: function returns multiple recordsets: how to read in c#?

Tags: c#, postgresql, function, recordset

Using this link
http://www.sqlines.com/postgresql/npgsql_cs_result_sets
I have created the example, but it does not work:
There is my function:

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION show_cities_multiple() 
 RETURNS SETOF refcursor AS $$
    DECLARE
      ref1 refcursor; 
      ref2 refcursor;                             
    BEGIN
      OPEN ref1 FOR SELECT user_id, user_name FROM users;
      RETURN NEXT ref1; 

      OPEN ref2 FOR SELECT id, company FROM customers;
      RETURN NEXT ref2;      
    END;
    $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The 1st loop reads recordsets names only and that is all what I can read from the function.

```
         NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection(GetConnectionString());
                conn.Open();
                NpgsqlTransaction tran = conn.BeginTransaction();
                NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand("show_cities_multiple", conn);
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                NpgsqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader();
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                   Console.Write("{0}\n", dr[0]);
                }
// ----------there is output - only names of cursors recordsets
// <unnamed portal 1>
// <unnamed portal 2>

                dr.NextResult(); 
// But there is nothing to read, no additional recordsets
                while (dr.Read())
                    Console.Write("{0}\t{1} \n", dr[0], dr[1]);

                tran.Commit();
                conn.Close();
```

What is wrong? How to read multiple recordsets from a PGSQL function?

Comment: You then should to execute `fetch all from "<unnamed portal 1>"` to get first result set and `fetch all from "<unnamed portal 2>"` to get second result set accordingly (substitute names by values returned from the function). [Documentation and examples](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-cursors.html#AEN66596)

Comment: It should be the separate NpgsqlCommand ? or where in my example I need to execute these commands?

Comment: Yes, it should be the separate command(s). It is up to you where to execute them, but it should be executed in the same transaction as the function.

Comment: Does it mean that there is incorrect code?  http://www.sqlines.com/postgresql/npgsql_cs_result_sets

Comment: Ok, just tested it with `mono` and the code almost same to yours works fine. I got the result like you described using `NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand("select * from show_cities_multiple()", conn);` instead of `NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand("show_cities_multiple", conn); command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;` Just FYI.

Comment: I have made again as you wrote: the 1st loop output is  <unnamed portal 1>
<unnamed portal 2>, dr.NextResult(); returns false. And btw, the  tran.Commit() generate an exception: {Npgsql.NpgsqlOperationInProgressException: A command is already in progress

Comment: Thanks! only one note: if you use a cursor the first call shuld be:command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
command.ExecuteNonQuery();

command.CommandText = "fetch all in \"<unnamed portal 1>\"";
command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways to work with cursors for different versions

[how can I get cursor data with calling stored procedure in npgsql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32862416/how-can-i-get-cursor-data-with-calling-stored-procedure-in-npgsql)