# How to call a PostgreSQL function which returns multiple ref cursor with C# to get data of ref cursor?

Tags: c#, postgresql

I have created function in PostgreSQL which returns multiple ref cursor. Now the problem is that how to write " Feth all from '' " statement in C# code.

I am executing below query in pg Admin 4  and I am getting data successfully.

```
select * from get_Dashboard_Graph('09/01/2018','09/28/2018'); 
FETCH All FROM "process_wise_positrol"; 
FETCH All FROM "process_wise_micro_audit"; 
FETCH All FROM "process_wise_positrol_line_stop"; 
FETCH All FROM "process_wise_micro_audit_line_stop";
```

Below is my C# code in which i am not getting how to write above query ?

```
public object process_wise_audit()
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            try
            {

                con.Open();
                List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();
                NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand();

                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.CommandText = "get_Dashboard_Graph";
                cmd.Connection = con;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(":p_fromdate", "08/01/2018");
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(":p_todate", "08/28/2018");

                NpgsqlDataAdapter da = new NpgsqlDataAdapter();
                da.SelectCommand = cmd;
                da.Fill(ds);
                con.Close();
                con.Dispose();
                // if (true)//(cmd.Parameters["msg"].Value.ToString() == "SUCCESS")
                //  {
                return ds;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return ds;
            }
            return ds;

        }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how can I get cursor data with calling stored procedure in npgsql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32862416/how-can-i-get-cursor-data-with-calling-stored-procedure-in-npgsql)