# How to fetch data from a database with a stored procedure?

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, npgsql

I need to fetch the data from a database with a stored procedure and then show it in a report.

I have this code:

```
conexion.Open();

NpgsqlCommand cm = new NpgsqlCommand("sp_reporte", conexion);
cm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@codigo", int.Parse(codigof.Text));

NpgsqlDataAdapter da = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(cm);

DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds);
```

but this code doesn't work because it doesn't bring me any data

This is how I have my stored procedure

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sp_reporte(codigo integer) 
RETURNS refcursor AS $$
DECLARE
  ref refcursor;                                                    
BEGIN
  OPEN ref FOR SELECT *
                FROM factura f
                INNER JOIN detallefactura d ON f.codigofactura = d.codigofactura
                WHERE f.codigo = codigo;  
  RETURN ref;                                                      
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: What does "doesn't let me" mean exactly? Do you get an error? Do you get no results?

Comment: I do not pass the data, I get empty

Comment: @Carlos, One thing I see, parameters for stored procedures should start with "@" symbol. So in your program:  ````cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@codigo", int.Parse(codigof.Text));```` This is true in your stored procedure as well.

Comment: Yes, that error was corrected, I forgot to change it in the question

Comment: @Carlos, And you are sure that you sql statement has results? It is just not passing into your datatable?

Comment: I tried it with parameters and without parameters and nothing worked.. ask my SP is ok like this or you have to change it

Comment: @Carlos, Are you missing the ExecuteNonQuery()?

Comment: I do not understand the question

Comment: @Carlos, sorry I am not completely familiar with  PostgreSQL, I use MSSQL. I am assuming it is very similar. In your c# code, after you create the NpgsqlCommand, you have to execute it. Something like ```cm.ExecuteNonQuery()```.

Comment: it doesn't work for me

Comment: @Carlos You need to eliminate that phrase "it doesn't work for me" from your vocabulary. That tells us nothing. Instead, describe exactly what you tried, and how exactly it failed or deviated from what you desire.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use with SqlConnection,

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection()) {
    connection.ConnectionString = YourConnectingString;

    using (var command = new SqlCommand(procedure, connection)) {
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.Parameters.Add("@codigo", SqlDbType.Int).Value = int.Parse(codigof.Text);

        connection.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        using (var da = new SqlDataAdapter(command)) {
            da.Fill(_dt);
        }
    }
}
```

Like I said in the comment section above, I am not familiar with PostgreSQL, so I can't really say if your stored procedure is correct...

I think your stored procedure needs to declare the @codigo variable, like you have for refcursor. And in the code

```
WHERE f.codigo = @codigo;
```

Comment: Should not use executenonquery. This is expecting no result. Should be used for update, insert or delete statements (or stored procedures without any result) right now i cant remember the function you should call, but think its something like executereader.

Comment: @MrZach, that's interesting - I use this all the time and get data from it. I looked up the documentation and found - "Although the ExecuteNonQuery returns no rows, any output parameters or return values mapped to parameters are populated with data." But you are right, it should be 'ExecuteReader'. Thanks.

Comment: I can't throw this error either:   A command is already in progress: reporte'

Answer (score 0):

Please see Shay Rojansky's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32862416/how-can-i-get-cursor-data-with-calling-stored-procedure-in-npgsql).
What you need to do, is to change your `FUNCTION` to return a `TABLE` or `SETOF`.  Incidentally there are differences in `postgreSQL` between procedures and functions, albeit not particularly relevant here: to be accurate though, you are using a function not a procedure.
One advantage of this approach is that you will be forced to specify the fields and types returned, meaning that you will not be able to do `SELECT *`. Although this is more work on your side, it is a good thing as it makes your code much safer in the long run. If you need help with the syntax for the return type, please let me know.